# how to get an item inside a response object

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

i am trying to get a value inside a response but i am getting null

[image]

this image is a response of an url but when i try to access it i am getting undefined

```
this.http.post(url, data, headers)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.devicePlaylist[0]);
                console.log("play list   :", res[1]);
            }, (err) => {
                console.log("failed", err);
            });
```

i an getting the res as object but i coulc not access devicePlaylist, could someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your outer object in console is the response ;can you try log `res.Response.devicePlaylist[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have printed the the `res` object as `console.log(res)` inside the `subscribe` method, check the browser console and notice that `Object` written there. This means that the value `res` is an object and it contains `key : value` pair. So when you try to access `console.log(res.devicePlaylist[0]);` then you will not find that printed in the console since `res` do not have a key named `devicePlaylist`. Thus, `devicePlaylist` is inside the key `Response` of `res`. So, you need to access it as,

```
res.Response.devicePlaylist[0]
```

And, since `devicePlaylist` is an array (also displayed as an array in the browser console), you can use the index value 0 until the array `devicePlaylist` contains at least one element. Otherwise, you will get `undefined` if the array is empty.